# jBPM web designer - install and usage

Tags: designer, jbpm

Has anyone got the new jBPM 4.3 web designer installed and working? I am trying to but http://localhost:8080/jbpmeditor/, http://localhost:8080/jbpm/editor/; http://localhost:8080/p/explorer all return invalid URL

I have run ant install.signavio.into.tomcat. I am on tomcat 6.0, jBPM4.3, MySQL 5.1. I am able to login to the jbpm-console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://localhost:8080/jbpmeditor/p/explorer

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the **standalone jbpm-designer** application (current version is 2.4.0), the URL of the application instance is:

```
http://localhost:8080/designer/editor?profile=jbpm
```

Looks like **guvnor** is a mandatory dependency (it is available from [Maven Central](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/guvnor-webapp)) and needs to be deployed in the same Application Server at:

```
http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor
```